# where is the "kill" function that sent signal in mingw?

Tags: c++, c, visual-c++, mingw

I compiled my code with mingw in windows xp.
I want to sent SIGINT signal to child thread.But the header file of "signal.h" don't include "kill" function.
The function raise(SIGINT) will finish the program.I have to use kill(pid,SIGINT) to work.But no function.

Comment: `kill()` can not be used to send a signal to a **specific thread**. The signal is sent to the **process** referred by `<pid>` and it is left to the implementation to decide which of the process's thread will receive and handle the signal. Which thread lib are you using?

Comment: The thread lib is wxThread that come from wxWidgets.

Comment: On how to terminate a `wxThread` this http://docs.wxwidgets.org/stable/wx_wxthread.html#deletionwxthread might be of interest.

Comment: @alk,Yes,I have read the doc.I don't want to call the wxThread::TestDestroy function in each loop.

Comment: If you read the doc you know about wxThread::Kill though.

Comment: @alk,The wxThread::Kill isn't safe.I have tried to call wxThread::Kill.First,thread have stoped.Then,I tried to creat another new thread,but it failed and the process exited.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at the Win32 function [TerminateProcess](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms686714%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

Comment: Previously, I only work in linux.I don't know what is HANDLE. Seeing the document is so trouble.can you tell me how to kill the child thread by PID.

Comment: @simon: In Windows, threads and processes are separate things (that's true in linux too).  A thread is not uniquely identified by a PID, each process (and PID) may have many threads.

Comment: Please ignore my answer.  I had misread your question and thought you were talking about a child *process*, not just a thread.  There are API functions to terminate threads, but that's only relevant if you used the corresponding functions to create the thread.

Comment: Do not kill threads in Win32.  Let them exit naturally unless you want all kinds of funny resource leaks.  Killing a thread that holds a semaphore or mutex can cause said semaphore or mutex to be held forever unless you take action to clean it up.

Comment: This child thread is a socket server writed by python that called in c++.It will loop and block.so I have to stop with signal.

Comment: @simon: Do you understand the difference between a thread and a process?

Answer (score 0):

The kill function is part of the c stardard library and represents a system call, which send a specified signal to the targeted process.
As you use mingw, it don't use the glibc library, but gnulib instead to compile, so you should check the corresponding gnulib function.

Comment: As i was looking for more informations about mingw and the system calls invoked by kill, i found that sentence in the [MinGW wiki](http://www.mingw.org/wiki/MinGW) :
"MinGW doesn't provide Linux or Unix system calls or a POSIX emulation layer.  Some POSIX compatibility is provided by the supported runtime library, msvcrt.dll."

I couldn't find more informations about kill remplacement, so you should look for a new way to handle threads in mingw.

Comment: Oh yes, Cygwin is the project (complementary to mingw) that adds a support layer for Unix system calls based on the `newlib` C runtime library.

Comment: Maybe I can try on the `newlib`.

Answer (score 0):

mingw does not support kill on windows. You can use SendMessage to the window of the other thread and let it handle it and die gracefully. For non-windowed apps use events (CreateEvent / WaitForSingleObject) as a communication mechanism with the 'child' threads.